# how to always check a condition in the background in android?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I have an application in which user enters the two time from time picker and i want to run a code particularly in that time interval. So, my problem is how to always check the current time to the time entered by the user and also this service is to be run in the background.
What are the possible ways to run this service always for checking the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what is the code to be executed, you may be needing [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the service and check the condition whatever you want or you can use the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You may create two [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), one to start a service with the code you want to run and the other to end it. You can then use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule the execution of the receivers code to the proper time.